# Zip exception, duplicate entry com/quickblox/BuildConfig.class

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have build a simple chat apps using quickblox in `android studio2.2.1`, its working fine with `quickblox-android-0.8.1.jar`. 
But now i want to add attachment to it. I am using four more individual `.jar` for that`(content, core, messages, chat  2.5.1)`.
I have followed quickblox website guidance. But getting zip exception duplicate entry `com/quickblox/BuildConfig.class`. What am i doing wrong?  help
[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9XRj.png)

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9XRj.png]]

Comment: please show your gradle file

Comment: Sir, which one??? App level or Project level gradle??

Comment: project, we need to check your dependencies part

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-messages-2.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-content-2.5.1.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

Comment: Please add it to your origin question and format properly

Comment: Sir, i think quick-android-sdk-0.8.2.jar and quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.5.1.jar, these two jar (with two other jar) are creating exception.sir is it necessary to add this quick-android-sdk-0.8.2.jar? i have tried removing the quick-android-sdk-0.8.2.jar but after that there are so many problem like 'QBCallback cannot be resolve' etc.  So feeling very helpless with Quickblox at that moment. what should i do??

Comment: Answered your question separately

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove **quickblox-android-sdk-0.8.2.jar** dependency and replace it with

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
        }
    }
}

def qbSdkVersion = '2.5.1'

dependencies {
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:$qbSdkVersion"
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:$qbSdkVersion"
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:$qbSdkVersion"
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:$qbSdkVersion"
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:$qbSdkVersion"
}
```

And also,

you have to adapt your code to QuickBlox Android SDK 2.x family.
Android SDK 0.8 is too old and it was some majot changes in 1.x and 2.x.

However, I recommend you to updated to latest 3.3 version https://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Framework_changelog

Comment: i have added library as per your suggestion but this time i m not getting many Quickblox method like QBCallback. so what should i do??

Comment: I propose you to start from here https://quickblox.com/developers/Android
, how to work with latest QuickBlox API

Comment: sir, i have followed quickblox site as per your advice for the new sdk3.3.0 but i do not understand the flow of Signin process. it has vastly change the entire conception in new quickblox sdk. sir, i just want to know the Flow of Signin(user).plz help in this context.

Comment: here it is https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Sign_In_.26_Social_authorization

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i am getting nullpointerexception when login button click, btw i am using quickblox sdk 2.5.1